# div#d1 toggle on p#1 click - howTo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle a div when its name is clicked.

- I have multiple coupls like that in my page, and I want it to work as
  "when `<p id= "d2">` is clicked => `<div id="d2">` is toggled".

**I tried those functions:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $("div#" + $(this).attr('id')).toggle();
    });
});

function rgt() {
    //document.body.innerHTML = "";
    var id = "d" + this.id;
    var situation = document.getElementById(id).style.display;

    if (situation == "none") {
        situation = "block";
    }
    else {
        situation = "none";
    }
}

 function showHide(theId) {
    if (document.getElementById("d" + theId).style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById("d" + theId).style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("d" + theId).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I can't make it Work!!! Why is it?

the browser says:**"no 'display' property for null"...**

I will be more than happy to solve it with simple jquery

Comment: What does your HTML markup look like?

Comment: Wait, are you putting the same id on the p as the div? (Your p click handler makes it look like you are)  You can't do that.  Ids must be unique per page.

Answer (score 2):

**Ensure Your `id` Attributes Are Unique**

Assuming that your `id` attributes are unique, which [they are required to be per the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute):

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.

You should consider renaming your  `id` attributes to `d{n}` and your paragraphs to `p{n}` respectively as seen below :

```
<button id='p1'>p1</button> <button id='p2'>p2</button> <button id='p3'>p3</button>
<div id='d1'><pre>d1</pre></div>
<div id='d2'><pre>d2</pre></div>
<div id='d3'><pre>d3</pre></div>
```

which would allow you to use the following function to handle your toggle operations :

```
$(function(){
  // When an ID that starts with P is clicked
  $('[id^="p"]').click(function(){
      // Get the proper number for it
      var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace(/\D/g,''));
      // Now that you have the ID, use it to toggle the appropriate <div>
      $('#d' + id).toggle();
  })
});
```

**Example Using Unique IDs**

You can [see an interactive example of this approach here](http://jsbin.com/ciwedu/2/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

**Consider Using `data-*` Attributes**

HTML supports the use of data attributes that can be useful for targeting specific elements through jQuery and associating them to other actions. For instance, if you create an attribute on each of your "p" elements as follows :

```
<button data-toggles='d1'>p1</button>
<button data-toggles='d2'>p2</button>
<button data-toggles='d3'>p3</button>
```

and then simply change your jQuery to use those as selectors :

```
$(function(){
    // When an element with a "toggles" attribute is clicked
    $('[data-toggles]').click(function(){
         // Then toggle its target
         $('#' + $(this).data('toggles')).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Or, potentially, a custom `data-*` attribute, such as (for example) `<p data-affects="d2">` but any attribute other than `id` would work.

Comment: I agree. This is an ideal case for data attributes, I'll provide an example of that approach as well.

Comment: For completion, because I had time *and* another answer seemed redundant, might I offer some plain JS alternatives, using changed `id` properties: ["p1", "d1"](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3zdo7ztz/) and using [`data-*` attributes](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3zdo7ztz/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Is this you are looking?

```
$("#p1").on("click", function() {
    $("#d1").toggle();
 });
```

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Jomet/09yehw9y/

Comment: While this would be valid, you need to show, or explain, *why* it works, and what problem this solution corrects.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($){
  var $toggles = $('.divToggle');
  var $togglables = $('.togglableDiv');
  
  $toggles.on('click', function(){
    //get the div at the same index as the p, and toggle it
    $togglables.eq($toggles.index(this)).toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="divToggle">Show Me 1</p>
<p class="divToggle">Show Me 2</p>
<p class="divToggle">Show Me 3</p>
<div class="togglableDiv">Weeee 1</div>
<div class="togglableDiv">Weeee 2</div>
<div class="togglableDiv">Weeee 3</div>
```

Minimal approach using classes.  This solution assumes the order of the p elements in the dom are in the same order as the divs are in the order.  They do not have to be contiguous, but the order does matter with this solution.

Comment: While this will work, please do take the time to explain/state your assumptions regarding the order of the elements. Otherwise there's a good chance that a working solution will break unexpectedly once changes are made by the op.

Answer (score 0):

### `ids` are not the droids you are looking for.

An id needs to be unique. If you want to classify something one would suggest to use classes. You can actually use serveral of them for some fancy stuff. How about something like this:

```
<p class="toggle one">one</p>
<div class="toggle one" style="display:none">content one</div>
```

Straight forward. Every element that is a switch or switchable gets the class `toggle`. Each pair of switch and switchable(s) gets an additional identifier (like `one`, `two`, `...`).

---

**Simple JScript Implementation:**

Now how about not using JQuery to work with that? Sure it i$ handy, but it hides all that neat stuff one would eventually like to learn her/himself!

```js
var myToggle = {};
(function(module) {
  "use strict";

  (function init() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
    var element;

    var i = elements.length;
    while (i) {
      i -= 1;

      element = elements[i].className;
      elements[i].setAttribute("onclick", "myToggle.swap(\"" + element + "\")");
    }
  }());

  module.swap = function(element) {
    var couple = document.getElementsByClassName(element);

    var i = couple.length;
    while (i) {
      i -= 1;

      if (couple[i].style.display === "none" && couple[i].tagName === "DIV") {
        couple[i].style.display = "block";
      } else if (couple[i].tagName === "DIV") {
        couple[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  };
}(myToggle));
```

```html
<p class="toggle one">one</p>
<div class="toggle one" style="display:none">content one</div>

<p class="toggle two">two</p>
<div class="toggle two" style="display:none">content two 1</div>
<div class="toggle two" style="display:none">content two 2</div>
```

`var myToggle = {}` is the object we use to keep our little program contained. It prevents that our code conflicts with other declarations. Because what if some plugin on our site already declared a function called `swap()`? One would overwrite the other!
Using an object like this ensures that our version is now known as `myToggle.swap()`!

It may be hard to follow how it got to that name. Important hint: something looking like this... `(function() { CODE } ())` ...is called an `immediately-invoked function expression`. *iffy!* It's a function that is immediatly executed and keeps its variables to itself. Or can give them to whatever you feed it in the last ()-pair.

Everything else is as verbose as can be... no fancy regular expressions, hacks or libraries. Get into it!